# Show shortcode only in posts

Tags: shortcode

I created a shortcode to show the short URL from a post. I use canvas, that has an option to show shortcode after content, but I only want to show the shortcode only in posts, not in homepage.

How is possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question:

Modify the shortcode to incorporate

```
<?php if (is_post()) { //do this; }?>
```

or

```
<?php if (is_page()) { //do this; }?>
```

or

```
<?php if (is_home()||is_front_page()) { //do this; }?>
```

The first will only do //do this; on a post, the second on a page, and the third if the post or page is the homepage.

Comment: `is_post()` is deprecated - use `is_single()` instead: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post